# after Disabled Bitnami banner, Apache not running, Httpd could not be started

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-web-services, bitnami

I went to restart Apache after disabling the banner with

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/bnconfig --disable_banner 1
```

now Apache won't restart

```
~$ sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh status
php-fpm already running
apache not running
mysql already running
```

I tried

```
~$ sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh start apache
Syntax OK
/opt/bitnami/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd could not be started
```

Monitored apache

for error log -  `cat /opt/bitnami/apache2/logs/error_log`
you can find it here in this link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f2Xt0bwcMEhKcXkILLMf_kdBl0JoSZUr/view?usp=sharing

for *httpd-app.conf* file here copy of it in below link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l2zEPzIU0uBHdEyFQEZ22eEPS9fMnBTO/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

When looking at (error) log files the most recent ones are at the bottom and those are usually the most relevant when an application fails to start.

That shows that the problem is not the banner but something else:

> [Fri Jul 20 23:52:07.232239 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 2058:tid 140169115285248] AH0                                                                                                                2565: Certificate and private key localhost:443:0 from /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf                                                                                                                /server.crt and /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.key do not match
>   AH00016: Configuration Failed

Your problem is in the SSL configuration and the private key `server.key` does not belong to the certificate `server.crt`. You will need to fix that by using the correct files.

You can inspect TLS certificate files with `openssl`  and the *modulus* must match:

```
$ openssl x509 -noout -text -in server.crt
$ openssl rsa -noout -text -in server.key


$ openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in server.crt 
$ openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in server.key
```

Comment: I installed new SSL certificate now issue solved 
thank you a lot for you help

Comment: Please do not add a comment or an Answer to say "Thank you". - If you want to say "thank you," [vote up](http://serverfault.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that person's answer, or simply pay it forward by providing a great answer to someone else's question. - See [this FAQ page](http://serverfault.com/help/someone-answers) with regards to the etiquette on ServerFault and related sites. - (If this is an Answer to a Question you yourself asked then you additionally have the option to accept it as the correct answer.)